# Can I use OpenCV?

Tags: software-installation, opencv, computer-vision

While the Raspberry Pi is not exactly a powerhouse, it should be capable of doing some OpenCV image or video processing. Has anyone tried to install it?

Comment: Please see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41/can-i-use-the-gpu-for-calculations wrt GPU calculations.

Comment: Could be useful: http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/03/arm-wrestling-with-opencv/

Answer (score 14):

OpenCV is now available in apt-get. You can search for it:

```
apt-cache search opencv
```

If you are doing development, just do:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

At the time of this writing, it is OpenCV 2.3

Comment: This deserves more upvotes

Comment: Beware the libopencv-dev version via apt probably does not get updated in the repos... as of April 2015 the package version is stuck at 2.4.1 still while the latest version is 2.4.11. If you need a newer version you have to compile OpenCV from sources most likely.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible to install OpenCV on the Raspberry Pi using either Debian Squeeze or Arch Linux ARM. As done in the following two blog posts, it should just be a matter of either installing or compiling.

- [Installing OpenCV on the Raspberry Pi (Debian)](http://eduardofv.com/read_post/185-Installing-OpenCV-on-the-Raspberry-Pi)
- [OpenCV on the Raspberry Pi with Arch Linux ARM](http://eduardofv.com/read_post/192-OpenCV-on-the-Raspberry-Pi-with-Arch-Linux-ARM)

For prosperity's sake, you need to install `opencv` via pacman on Arch Linux ARM and compile it on Debian. Like so.

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/ \
  opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2/download
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
  -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Your biggest problem will be performance though. It seems that OpenCV has a GPU
module designed to utilize GPU computational capabilities, though. It is implemented using NVidia's CUDA Runtime API though, so you will need a NVidia GPU in order to utilize the GPU capabilities. For more information, you should read [the wiki page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU).

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty straightforward if you compile every thing on the RPi, I couldn't get a cross compiler to work and the camera/webcam was slow/unresponsive
So my answer is yes but . . . depends what you want to do with it :)