# Does have Raspberry Pi enough performance for Computer vision process in c++

Tags: performance, c++, computer-vision

I will write a computer vision application in C++. I need to choose a hardware platform. I cannot use a PC (laptop, desktop, etc). I will process a video that I take a camera.

Can I use a Raspberry Pi? I mean, is the Raspberry Pi powerful enough for computer vision? If not do what hardware should I get? If the Raspberry Pi is enough, which model should I get?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please have a look at those [questions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opencv) to further narrow down your question, e.g. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/409/can-i-use-opencv should give you a first impression what is possible.

Comment: Thank you. Is Raspberry Pi standart model or it has several different model that has different CPUs.

Comment: There are different models. The most powerful (quadcore CPU and 1 GB RAM) would be the [Pi2 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b) (or Pi2 for short).

Comment: The RPi is certainly capable of vision processing. We can't hope to give you a decent answer on whether or not the RPi will meet your needs with the given information. What's the required latency? How much video? What resolution? What kind of of vision processing?

Comment: As to the other part of your question... Shopping recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: OK, I should see model of hardware, now I have not my program, I will design several weeks but I should buy a hardware, thanks for interesting.

Comment: There are certainly projects using the capabilities of the Raspberry Pi and either the custom Camera Module or various Linux supported USB web-cameras / video cameras wired up to video capture devices.  Whether any of these will meet your needs depends on what sort of requirements you actually have - i.e. single image / video stream (and if the latter what size of image and frame rates) and how quickly you need it processed ("Real-time" or within a certain time or "as long as it takes").  Certainly the quad-core & 1GB memory RP 2B is the most power option but I think we need more information!

Comment: And 5min video, view the highway in a car, an example video I find internet : http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/video/automatised-car-exiting-the-autobahn-view-through-stock-video-footage/144487429. I should find lines of way and plates.

Comment: Come on guys. Give him a break. He could have simply replaced "buy" with "get" and it'll pretty much remove the *shopping recommendation* notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's powerful enough. I've used it in an OpenCV project before. You may have to lower your resolution a bit to get the best speed.

If you want to use a first-generation Pi (single core), just go ahead and compile it. If you want to use the quad-core Pi, you will have to compile it with *multithread* support. I'll leave it to you to figure it out.

It's up to you which one you'll get, but I prefer the Pi 2 Model B (quad-core). You may want to consider power consumption if you plan on powering your project using a bettery.