# OpenCL / GPGPU programming coming soon?

Tags: software-development, gpu

Last June the answer was a qualified no:
[Can I use the GPU for calculations?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41/can-i-use-the-gpu-for-calculations)

However, the Videocore driver code was open sourced towards the end of 2012:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2221 - does that mean we're now likely to see it happen?

If so, given existing libraries (http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl, http://www.jocl.org/) might already work, but with a CPU implementation, it would seem reasonable to start using them in the hope they'll soon be able to use the GPU.

Comment: If someone would like to create "opencl" and/or "gpgpu" tags feel free to re-tag this question.

Comment: Note that it's not accurate to say that "Videocore driver code was open sourced". Only part of it - running on ARM side was (and really important code is running on VideoCore itself and community have no way to do any changes to it). So this may be not enough for such implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situtation dramatically changed in 2014 with the [official release of documentation](https://www.broadcom.com/blog/chip-design/android-for-all-broadcom-gives-developers-keys-to-the-videocore-kingdom/) on the QPU units in the Pi GPU. The blog featured several GPGPU projects after that. Since then , the number of Pi GPGPU projects 
has risen.

See for example
"GPGPU python library for the Raspberry Pi" : https://github.com/nineties/py-videocore

Answer (score 3):

[OpenMAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMAX) is supported. It does not let you do arbitrary computations on the GPU, but it seems to contain compression and decompression of audio, video and images. [This thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=15463&hilit=decoding%20image%20with%20openmax) is about JPEG decompression with OpenMAX on the Pi.

[Here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VideoCore_APIs) is a list of API:s supported by the VideoCore.

Comment: Looks like there's some progress on this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/gpgpu-hacking-on-the-pi/